# How to hide a MDI Child form in Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, mdi

How can I hide a MDIChild window in Delphi?

I'm using this code in FormClose() event of my MDI children, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
procedure TfrmInstrument.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caNone;
  ShowWindow(Handle, SW_HIDE);
  frmMainForm.MDIChildClosed(Handle);
end;
```

My child window is minimized instead of being hidden.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand When I click the red cross, default behavior is to minimize a mdi child window in Delphi. I want to hide the window instead.

Comment: iMan: Good point. Now I see what you mean. You don't want to minimize, and you don't want to destroy. You want to hide it temporarily, so that you can show it again, later. I don't know if that is possible. [Well, the obvious solution is indeed to destroy it, and then create a new similar window when you need it.]

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I don't want to destroy and recreate a similar window because each child window loads a few libraries, opens a serial port, and some other initialization stuff which takes a few seconds. So, I create all my child forms at start up, hide them using `ShowWindow`, which ironically works there, show them when the user chooses one, and want to hide them again when the user closes them

Comment: @iManBiglari: If you move all your components and corresponding code into a data module for each MDI child window and treat the MDI child window as a simple view (which can be opened and closed at will) then you won't need to fight the MDI Windows subsystem. I dare say program design would be improved by such a change too.

Comment: @mghie I don't agree, because my child windows are totally atomic. They do not reference any other unit besides the usual RTL and VCL ones, and my main form - just no notify it of being closed.

Comment: @mghie Well, a frame would be more appropriate than a data module.

Comment: @iManBiglari: I fail to see how that matters at all. But if you are set on implementing it in a single unit then create a unit-private worker class that contains everything instead of using data modules. Bonus points for implementing it with threads, so the user doesn't have to wait for your longish initialization routines to complete, and so they can possibly run in parallel.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I don't think so if the aim is to have the components be contained in an object instance that can exist on its own, and the MDI child window just to be a view onto this.

Comment: @mghie The frame can exist on its own surely. Hide it and re-parent it. If it can't be parented to nil, then re-parent it to a hidden form. Do data modules admit visual components?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That would just make the MDI child form the container for the frame, and the frame would still contain model and view. A data module would enforce some separation between model and view, precisely because it can't contain visual components. That's why I suggested it in the first place.

Comment: @mghie I don't see why you need data modules to achieve that separation. I suppose it saves you writing the boilerplate code to instantiate components, but I've never found that particularly compelling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a protected procedure in `TCustomForm` defined as:

```
procedure TCustomForm.VisibleChanging;
begin
  if (FormStyle = fsMDIChild) and Visible and (Parent = nil) then
    raise EInvalidOperation.Create(SMDIChildNotVisible);
end;
```

Override it in your MDI child windows as:

```
procedure TMDIChildForm.VisibleChanging;
begin
  // :-P
end;
```

[Here's a simple example](http://www.yousendit.com/download/TEhVblRwMHczeUpEZU1UQw)

After reading Jeroen's comment, I tried another solution which works as well, but with a little flickering:

```
procedure TMDIChildForm.VisibleChanging;
begin
  if Visible then
    FormStyle := fsNormal
  else
    FormStyle := fsMDIChild;
end;
```

Maybe this works on all Windows versions.

PS: I didn't find any problem with the first solution on Windows 2k3SP2 x86 and Windows 7 Ultimate x86

Comment: MDI support in Windows contains a number of bugs that are (or at least were when I looked at this in the 90's) on the "won't fix" list at Microsoft. This is one of the reasons that hardly any Microsoft application that looks like MDI is actually using the Windows MDI code. TCustomForm.VisibleChanging is preventing those bugs to show their ugly head. So your suggestion might cause your applications to fail on certain versions of Windows.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers Then look at the other answer. Maybe this will bypass all those bugs

Comment: +1; That other answer (setting `FormStyle`) will indeed bypass those bugs. I'm pretty sure the bugs were there from Windows 3.0 till around Windows 2000. After that I've switched to SDI and Outlook style apps only.

Comment: I would test solution 1 extensively on all target OS versions. If it works I'd say go for it. My guess is that the reasons behind `TCustomForm.VisibleChanging` are lost in the depths of time. Perhaps you could ask about it on the Emba forums and see if any of the old time Emba devs can remember the reasoning.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan So far it works on XP SP3, 2k3 SP2, and 7 SP1. This weekend I'll look in my closets for my 2k installation CD, and I guess any older OS would be a waste of time.

Comment: UK submarines I believe were recently refurbished to use Win2k

Comment: I even see DOS, Windows 95 and Windows NT 4 solutions in the industrial area on a regular base. Most of them standalone systems interfacing with machinery.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide an MDI child window. This is a Win32 limitation.

Comment: But how come mdi child windows resist the `ShowWindow()` API call?

Comment: Because such windows aren't designed to be hidden?

Comment: I believe Andreas is correct, but I'm not sure why this design decision was taken. No doubt you already tried to call `Hide` and then gave up when the VCL raised the "Cannot hide an MDI child window" error. But that's the VCL's way of telling you that this is not supported.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I peeked a little inside Vcl.Forms.pas` and found this procedure:

    `procedure TCustomForm.VisibleChanging;
    begin
      if (FormStyle = fsMDIChild) and Visible and (Parent = nil) then
        raise EInvalidOperation.Create(SMDIChildNotVisible);
    end;`

I overrode it in my mdi child form, and my form got hidden the first time. But the second time it minimized itself again. So I guess I'm on the right track

Comment: No I don't think so. That exception is there because MDI and hidden child forms do not mix. Removing the code that raises the exception doesn't change that fundamental issue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan After wandering a little in delphi source files, I found out that `VisibleChanging` is called in TControl, and is overridden only in TCustomForm. I changed my code to change `Visible` instead of calling `ShowWindow`, and now everything works. I just found something weird. After hiding my form, its handle changes. Though this does not concern me, I'm interested in finding out why.

Comment: Does tiling your MDI children work also, when some of them are hidden

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes. I can tile and cascade my _visible_ windows with no apparent ill effect.

Comment: Tiling and cascading don't work for me when I try your solution.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Let me see if I can create a mock up application. My main application uses smart cards for user authentication and would be hard to get to work on your system.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan [Check this out](http://www.yousendit.com/download/TEhVblRwMHczeUpEZU1UQw)

Comment: Very nice. I think I realise why my app behaves differently. I do my own tiling! To avoid flicker and various other reasons. Anyway, I bet my code is not checking for hidden windows and ignoring them. Your solution looks good. I would test extensively on all target OS versions though, just to be sure. Good work!